# Setting credentials for img basic authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, iis-6, image, ntlm

I am developing a internal .Net application in VS2010 for deployment within my company's intranet. The site uses Windows Authentication so that users do not have to log in when they are successfully authenticated to the domain. For one page, it is required that I get some information from the intranet including photos and other information. For the employee photo, I am using a control:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" Style="display: inline-block" runat="server" CssClass="EmployeePhoto"
                alt="Photo not available" />
```

From the back end, this allows me to change which photo is displayed depending on user choices by changing the photo url as follows:

```
imgPhoto.ImageUrl = string.Format("http://{0}/{1}.jpg", MySitePath, employeePhotoPath);
```

The path is password protected however.Is there any way to explicitly provide the credentials used to access the asp:image so that I can pass in the credentials of the current authenticated user without the user being prompted to authenticate?

**UPDATE**

There used to be a way to specify the username + password into the img tag like:

```
<img src="http://username:password@server/photos/1.jpg">
```

or something similar. So that the credentials are available to access the directory? Is this possible in any way now?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using? It's important.  Also, you have three different problems intertwined here.  The first about firefox is solvable; however, the second one about just using anonymous is kind of buried in your question.  The third, regarding a third party which isn't sophisticated enough to pass a username and password.. well, it kind of brings up a question about why you were trying to go down the NTLM path to begin with.

Comment: I'm using IIS V6.0 running on a Windows 2003 server.The PDF service we are using simply goes to the URL we give it, loads the page and exports it to a PDF. I can't pass a username/password to the service, so I'm really trying to find a way to programmaticly (not quite a word I know) set the username and password used to get the photo from the intranet. I only used the Firefox issue for a more concrete example of the issue. My "Anonymous" page is set to use a Windows domain user account to authenticate and has the permissions to access the intranet photos. How can I not use NTLM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the WebClient class to set the credentials to authenticate to the other server and then download the photo locally:

```
                WebClient myWC = new WebClient();                    
                myWC.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(bioSearchUsername, bioSearchPassword);
                string photoPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/Employees/" + employee + ".jpg");
                myWC.DownloadFile(imageLocation, photoPath);
```

After that, I referenced the local copy of the photo on the server:

```
imgPhoto.ImageUrl = photoPath;
```

This got around the authentication problems I was running into with the image.

Answer (score 1):

See:
http://www.1stbyte.com/2008/03/15/automatic-windows-authentication-with-firefox-networkautomatic-ntlm-authtrusted-uris/

or, if you want an addon to manage that:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/integrated-auth-for-firefox/

Comment: That is helpful but that only works for my machine. I need a solution for everyone that needs to use the app. Also, this won't resolve the external service being unable to get to the intranet resources. thanks for the suggestion